# TeamPass how to download

Tags: server, wget

I am trying to setup TeamPass but having an issue trying to download the zip in my Ubuntu server.

I am using wget but it get 404 error

```
wget https://github.com/nilsteampassnet/TeamPass/archive/master.zip
```

It can resolve github.com and connect to github but I get http request sent, awaiting reponse .. 404 not found.

Do I need to install github itself on my server?

Just trying to download the zip

Comment: Have you retried? YMMV, but I just used the URI with `wget` and `Epiphany Web Browser` and both worked (gave me TeamPass-master.zip, Length: 9060127 (8.6M) [application/zip]. I'm in Canada, YMMV. No you don't need to install github.

Comment: Downloads fine here as well...